# column ordering in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm beginner to bootstrap and I saw column ordering which is awesome. But I tried to order my simple two column but seeming very difficult to me. So how should I implement this?

large screen:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|   A       |     B     |
+-----------------------+
```

small screen:

```
+----------+
|   B      |
+----------+
|   A      |
+----------+
```

---

I have html like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">A</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">B</div>
```

Nor for smaller screen I tried to change the ordering like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-pull-12">A</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-push-12">B</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.pull-right` on medium/large devices (and inverse your columns). As your extra-small/small devices use full width columns, this won't affect your layout.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 pull-right">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">A</div>
</div>
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/115398)

**XS/SM devices :**

```
| +-------------------+ |
| |         B         | | // 100% width, float:right as no effect
| +-------------------+ |
| |         A         | |
| +-------------------+ |
```

**MD/LG devices :**

```
| +---------+---------+ |
| |    B    |    A    | | // 50% width, float:right effect become visible
| +---------+---------+ |
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the divs to span 6 columns on large screens (or wherever you want the breakoff to be). By default they will span all 12 if it's smaller than the defined screen size.

---

## Edit

Sorry, I didn't understand the question. To swap the orderings, add a push the first div 6, and pull the second div 6 to switch their places on larger screens.

http://jsfiddle.net/8tEz2/1/

#### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the `column ordering`, as mentioned in the title **and** the question.